# Inotify ordering guarantee

Tags: c, linux, inotify

I have a directory I'm watching for changes with `inotify`. Here is how it looks like:

```
dir
 |
 |
  ---file.log
 |
 |
  ---file.log.moved (after moving `file.log`)
```

I have 3 processes. One moves `file.log` to `file.log.moved` another creates a new `file.log` instead of moved one and the third moves `file.log.moved` to another destination.

The question is do I have any ordering guarantees with inotify? I mean can I receive events in the following sequence:

```
IN_MOVED_FROM(file.log)
IN_CREATE(file.log)  //creating appears in between of moves
IN_MOVED_TO(file.log.moved)
```

or

```
IN_CREATE(file.log) //creating appears before moves
IN_MOVED_FROM(file.log)
IN_MOVED_TO(file.log.moved)
```

Comment: According to the man page: "The events returned by reading from an inotify file descriptor form an ordered queue. Thus, for example, it is guaranteed that when
renaming from one directory to another, events will be produced in the correct order on the inotify file descriptor."

Comment: @SirDarius Thanks, very useful. Maybe you know if it's guaranteed that for each, say, `read` syscall we receive only one `read` event?

Comment: Again according to the man page, it seems like a single read can return several events, though I'm not sure what you mean with a "read event", maybe you're talking about IN_ACCESS?